# I'm trying to print lines that have a matching string but would also like to print "NA" for the other lines

Tags: grep

I have a file that looks something like this:

```
Volume1  
created=Monday  
blah blah  
foo foo  
lock mode=exclusive  
ops  
layer id=1  

Volume2  
created=Tuesday  
jibber jabber  
foo foo  
ops  
layer id=2  

Volume3  
created=Wednesday  
blaaah  
foooo  
lock mode=shared  
ops  
layer id=3
```

What I'd like to do is grep on "lock mode" and if that is there print that whole line, otherwise I'd like to print "NA".  I can't seem to figure out how to print something for non-matching lines.  I'm sure awk or sed could do this as well.

I've been trying code similar to:

```
grep -A6 Volume | grep "lock mode" <file>
```

I'd like the output to show the following, for this example:

```
lock mode=exclusive  
NA  
lock mode=shared
```

Comment: Grep ping on a paragraph basis, then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With GNU **sed**

```
sed -n '
    /Volume/!d
    :a
    n
    /lock mode/{
        p
        d
        }
    /^\s*$/!ba
    c\NA
    ' <file>
```

With **awk**

```
awk '
    BEGIN{
        FS="\n"
        RS="\n\n"
    }
    /lock mode/{
        for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
            if($i ~ /lock mode/)
                print $i
        next
    }
    {
        print "NA"
    }
    ' <file>
```

Answer (score 3):

With `awk` in paragraph mode

```
awk -v RS= '{match($0, /lock mode=[^\n]+/); 
  print RSTART? substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH): "NA"}' file
```

The `RS=` causes each paragraph to be treated as a single record. The call to [match](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) populates the coordinates of `lock mode=....` into predefined variables `RSTART` and `RLENGTH`. If `RSTART`is non-zero, the substring corresponding to `RSTART` and `RLENGTH` is printed, otherwise `NA`is printed

Answer (score 3):

It's easy with `perl`:

```
perl -l -00 -ne 'print /lock mode.*/ ? $& : "NA"'
```

- `-l` sets the output field delimiter to newline
- `-00`: paragraph mode (records are paragraphs)
- `-ne code`: run code for every input record
- if the record contains `lock mode` followed by any number of non-newline characters, then print what is matched (`$&`) or `NA` otherwise.

Basically the same as [@iruvar's awk solution](/a/330952), but in `perl`.